# Add letters to DataTable in a column with only numeric values

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

**Question:**

> How can I allow a column in a DataTable to contain either 'just numeric values' or 'just letters'

So I'm building a small database/catalogue program for movies and naturally I want to include regions for different formats (for example DVD regions 1,2,3,4,0 and Blu-ray regions A,B,C,ABC)

The problem I'm getting is when I try to add Blu-ray regions to the column containing the DVD regions.

**Error message:**

[image: error message]

A quick overview so it can be understood better:

**Add form:**

[image: add form]

**DataGridView:**

[image: datagridview]

**Code:**

Note this works perfectly fine except when region contains letters.

```
Dim data As New DataTable()
```

This subroutine is called from another form and the variables are all declared as `Public X As String` inside a module:

```
Public Sub Addmovie()
    data.Rows.Add(AID, AShelf, ARow, ATitle, ADirector, ACountry, ALabel, AFormat, ARegion)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = data
End Sub
```

Initial datatable filling:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim name As [String] = "Sheet1"
        Dim constr As [String] = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + My.Settings.MSdbactive + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';"

        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr)
        Dim oconn As New OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con)
        con.Open()

        Dim sda As New OleDbDataAdapter(oconn)
        sda.Fill(data)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = data

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a "Type" table which stores all possibilities of regions for DVD/Blueray, that way you can expand later if regions for either are added, and you're using an autonumber to store in your table.  Put another way, your data isn't normalized by storing the actual values, normalize it so you have fewer places to make changes should the standard change over time.

Comment: Alright ill give it a go tomorrow. And i guess this means that i should look into programmatically create the columns to be able to give them a type table. As i have it now i use OleDbConnection and OleDbDataAdapter to fill the datatable from an excelfile where the first row from the excel file becomes the headers.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/) help - i.e. adding `IMEX=1` to the extended properties?